# Undelete comment on a Facebook Page

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages

The new Facebook Page Manager app (in combination with my less than stellar thumb accuracy) has had me inadvertently deleting comments (when I've been trying to like them) left and right. Is there any way to undo this?

If not, is there any way to tag a person who is a fan of the page and who commented on the post/picture but whose comment you deleted? I assume the answer is no since you cannot (acting as a page) tag someone in a reply who has not yet commented on a given post, but didn't know if anyone knew of any workarounds...

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no way to retrieve a deleted comment. Additionally, the rest of what you said is true, you will not be able to tag this person in the reply.